# How to add client side java script on a Acumatica Button

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I was wondering if it's possible to hook a Javascript onto a PXAction button. normally you can use the ClientEvents Property but with a button, these are not exposed.

The problem I am is every now and then there is a delay between the client and the server and the client will click the button a second time. I have server-side code to help stop this by disabling the button but I want to add a javascript to see if I can prevent it completely.

The code I want to add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var submit = 0;
   function CheckDouble() {
     if (++submit > 1) {
     alert('This sometimes takes a few seconds - please be patient.');
     return false;
   }
 }
 </script>
```

Any ideas or workaround I can maybe try?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the PXJavaScript control is what you are after.
I used this link to help get my head wrapped around how to use the control. We had a need to trigger something off with Java Script and the PXJavaScript control got us to the end result we needed.

[Dynamically Change Button Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006748/dynamically-change-button-color/56008485#56008485)

Let me know if this helps?
Robert

Comment: Hi Robert Thanks for the reply. the Problem is I can hook the JavaScript on to the button click.