# Acumatica - Changing textbox Font Color based on value

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I've been trying to modify the Projects (PM301000) screen summary area to change the font color of the totals to red when it's in negative value but I can't make it work. I've tried several javascript codes and saw that this is working on a button [Dynamically Change Button Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006748/dynamically-change-button-color/56008485)
but I can't make it work on the PXNumericEdit control specifically the totals in the Projects screen.

[Projects screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36HOH.png)

Any idea on how to make it work? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the Javascript code you currently have?

Comment: First troubleshooting step, put an "alert('test');" statement to make sure the JavaScript code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

You should try changing the CSS via an event handler in the aspx code behind file.  See this [article](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/12/using-colors-in-acumatica.html)